# How to register multiple native iOS views in flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I have two native views in flutter for iOS `CealQrViewNativeViewFactory` and `CealScanViewNativeViewFactory`. When I use them individually while commenting out the other one then it works but if I try to register both of them I get error saying

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Duplicate plugin key: <ceal-views>'
```

Below is my code in `AppDelegate's` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        
        weak var registrar = self.registrar(forPlugin: "ceal-views")
        let cealQrViewfactory = CealQrViewNativeViewFactory(messenger: registrar!.messenger())
        self.registrar(forPlugin: "<ceal-views>")!.register(
            cealQrViewfactory,
            withId: "cealQrView")
        
        let cealScanViewFactory = CealScanViewNativeViewFactory(messenger: registrar!.messenger())
        self.registrar(forPlugin: "<ceal-views>")!.register(
            cealScanViewFactory,
            withId: "cealScanQrView")
```

I have separate `swift` file for `CealScanViewNativeViewFactory` and `CealQrViewNativeViewFactory` where I have written `native swift code`

Comment: Try `let viewRegistrar = registrar(forPlugin: "<ceal-views>")!` and register your view factories with this single object

Comment: @DmytroRostopira I tried your code it does not work. You just replaced wear var with let. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: I've posted full snippet as answer, try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```swift
        weak var registrar = self.registrar(forPlugin: "ceal-views")
        let cealQrViewfactory = CealQrViewNativeViewFactory(messenger: registrar!.messenger())
        let viewRegistrar = self.registrar(forPlugin: "<ceal-views>")!
        viewRegistrar.register(
            cealQrViewfactory,
            withId: "cealQrView")
        
        let cealScanViewFactory = CealScanViewNativeViewFactory(messenger: registrar!.messenger())
        viewRegistrar.register(
            cealScanViewFactory,
            withId: "cealScanQrView")
```

Explanation: exception is thrown, because you created 2 registrars for the same plugin (`<ceal-views>` in this case)

Comment: Works like a charm!